# ¿¡No se puede insertar código (cualquier lenguaje) como si fuera un data en una tabla mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, mysqldb

Tengo un formulario que envia los datos a una página y esta los introduce a una tabla php dentro de una fila con tipo de dato, varchar(500). Funciona de maravilla, lo que introduzco en el formulario se introduce en la tabla.

Pero el problema está en que un día se me ocurrió introducir en este input un código simple de lenguaje php para almacenarlo en mysql. El código era este: `echo 'Hola';` . Pero en vez de almacenarlo de dice que ha habido un error y que no existe `mysqli_query($conn, $query);`, lo que debeía existir si funcionara bien. Es muy extraño, por que si meto una frase normal si que la almacena. ¿Acaso mysql no permite almacenar código? ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo? Muchas gracias de antelación. PD: me gustaría almacenarlo como texto, no como código ejecutable.
Este es el formulario:

```
<form action="publicar.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" id ="input" required placeholder="¡Crappea la estupidez del día!" 
 name="publicacion">
 <input type="text" id ="input2" value = "<?= $grupo2; ?>" name="grupo">
 <div id="avion2">
  <button type="submit" name="publicar">
     <img id="avion" src="Imagenes/avion.png">
   </button> 
  </div> 
</form>
```

Y este es el código de publicar.php que almacena los datos:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, email, password, nombre FROM usuarios WHERE id=:id');
    $records->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $user=null;
    if(count($results)>0){
        $user=$results;
    }
}
$conn = mysqli_connect(
    'localhost',
    'root',
    '',
    'crapping',
);

if (isset($_POST['publicar'])){
    $publicacion = $_POST['publicacion'];
    $nombre= $user['nombre'];
    $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO publicaciones(nombre, publicacion, grupo) VALUES ('$nombre', 
    '$publicacion', '$grupo')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (!$resultado){
    die("Ha habido un error.");
    }
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Task Saved';
    $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'success';
    header("location: Pagina.php?grupo2=".$grupo);
}
?>
```

Comment: Mysql va a guardar lo que le digas, siempre que el formato sea correcto. Por favor, pon el mensaje completo de error en la pregunta. Pero tiene pinta de que, en su estado actual, estás haciéndote SQL injection :P

Comment: @Alfabravo No me da ningún error propiamente dicho. Si no que como en el código tengo puesto que si resultado no existe me diga que ha habido un error, me imprime eso. ¿Y en el caso de que estuviera haciendo SQL injection cual seria el problema?

Comment: Fíjate en cómo el contenido del campo va entre comillas sencillas en tu consulta. Si el contenido tiene una comilla sencilla y no la escapas, la consulta termina ahí y queda mal formada. Por eso, además, dudo que no tengas errores. Posiblemente no hay revisado los logs de PHP :)

Comment: Tú puedes almacenar código en la base de datos, pero **la finalidad de una base de datos no es esa en absoluto**. Ahora bien, para hacerlo funcionar tendrás que hacer uso de `eval`  y esto puede ser muyyyy peligroso. Si pones este programa en producción, y permites almacenar código, te pueden mandar incluso una bomba y hacerla explotar en el servidor. Entonces la pregunta aquí es: ¿Hay algo que justifique realmente la peligrosísima practica que quieres implementar? Si en una piscina hay un cable eléctrico pelado y no hay luz te puedes meter, no problem, pero ¿y si llega la luz? ¡¡¡¡ !!!!

Comment: @A.Cedano Estoy haciendo una especie de caja de comentarios, en la que los usuarios puedan publicar lo que quieran, y como la pagina va sobre programación había pensado que igual querían comentar algo que contuviera código, aunque este no se ejecutara, sino que solo fuera tratado como un texto normal. Pero, por lo que has dicho, casi mejor no permitirles publicar código, más vale prevenir que curar. Gracias.

Comment: Tú puedes permitir código como texto siempre y cuando tomes todas las medidas para asegurar precisamente eso: **que el contenido se mostrará como texto**. En ese caso no hay problema. Pero en la pregunta lo que se interpreta (o al menos es lo que yo entendí en un principio) es que quieres permitir que ese código se ejecute y ahí la cosa cambia radicalmente.

Comment: Hoy día, con herramientas como Ajax o la API Fetch tú podrías traer ese contenido (almacenado en la base de datos del servidor) y mostrarlo en el cliente, usando una librería para la sintaxis incluso, logrando algo aceptable estéticamente y seguro porque en ningún caso habrá posibilidad de que el código se ejecute en el servidor.

Comment: @A.cedano Investigaré sobre ello. Muchas gracias